# delete $recycle.bin folder in all folders

Tags: batch-file, cmd, recycle-bin

Need a bit help here please...

need a script preferably batch script to delete $recycle.bin folder in all sub folders.

I have Drive where I have user folders and each user folder has his own $recycle.bin folder.

```
Structure on Drive C:\
User1 > $recycle.bin
User2 > $recycle.bin
User3 > $recycle.bin
```

When user deletes something on his profile then it sends to c:\user1\$recycle.bin. 
At the moment I go in each folder separately to delete $recycle.bin.

Comment: Write the script yourself and then come back here when it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this more or less single line batch file with folder path `C:\` to be replaced by real parent folder path:

```
@echo off
for /F %%D in ('dir "C:\$recycle.bin" /AD /B /S 2^>nul') do rd /Q /S "%%D" 2>nul
```

The command line above searches for folder `$recycle.bin` recursively in **all** directories of drive C: and deletes each found `$recycle.bin`.

There is also a second solution which is faster because of searching first only for non hidden folders in root of drive C: (user folder) and searching next in each found (user) folder for a folder `$recycle.bin` which is deleted if such a subfolder is really found in a user folder.

```
@echo off
for /D %%U in ("C:\*") do (
    for /F %%D in ('dir "%%U\$recycle.bin*" /AD /B 2^>nul') do rd /Q /S "%%U\%%D" 2>nul
)
```

The third solution is using second solution without searching for `$recycle.bin` in a user folder and instead simply assume that there is such a folder and delete it. If the subfolder of root of drive C: does not have a folder `$recycle.bin` an error message is output by command **RD**, but this error message is suppressed as explained below.

```
@echo off
for /D %%D in ("C:\*") do rd /Q /S "%%D\$recycle.bin" 2>nul
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `rd /?`

See also Microsoft article [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `2>nul`.

The error message output by command **DIR** to **STDERR** on not finding any folder with name `$recycle.bin` is suppressed by redirecting the error message to device **NUL** with `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with `^` to be applied on execution of command **DIR** instead of being interpreted as redirection of command **FOR** specified at an invalid position which would result in an exit of command processing because of a syntax error.

`2>nul` is also used on command **RD** to suppress the error message output on any folder or file inside the folder is currently in use by a user and therefore the deletion of the folder fails. On third solution it also suppress the error message if there is no folder `$recycle.bin` at all.